# UV map U direction refering to X or Y?

Tags: uv-image-editor

As for as my knowledge goes the UV in UV map is basically the same as X and Y direction.
So my question is does the U in UV refer to the X direction in the UV editor or the Y direction?

Comment: I presume U is for X and V is for Y but anyway I don't think you ever meet the need to press U or V, in the UV Editor you press X and Y to move the island on the horizontal and vertical axis

Comment: It's important because the tangent node uses the U directionof the UV map and having the directions incorrect obviously switches things.

Comment: oh ok I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the manual, in the UV editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv/introduction.html) “ . . . U is the left-right direction, and V is the up-down direction . . . We use U and V to refer to these ‘texture-space coordinates’ instead of the normal X and Y . . . ”

However, in any official documentation that (and similar) is how it's always referred to.  If they've ever flat-out, unequivocally said “U is X and V is Y” then I'm not spotting it.